# I would like to run my task on Ubuntu machine remotely along with its "local" user

Tags: remote-access

I have Windows 10 machine and I need to run some tasks, actually compile tex documents, on a remote Ubuntu machine. This is my wife's machine and I want her to be able to work on her machine along with me. Is it possible? How?

Comment: If you do not need a GUI (only text terminal), you could use ssh. Install `sshd`on the Linux machine (`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`), and download putty on your Windows box from `www.putty.org`. If you need a GUI, you might install `rdp` on Linux (`sudo apt-get install xrdp`), configure and connect via rdp from Windows.

Comment: @ridgy: Could you please convert that into a proper answer? Thanks. :-)